# How do I have more then one parameter on a single line for parameterized jobsin jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, multiple-choice

I would like to have my parameters input taken in a horizontal order from Jenkins ui rather than going by its default nature of being vertical.

Attaching the link of the exact question asked before but unresolved.

[issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31849)

Comment: it depends on where are you using this parameters, if in shell script. can't you take parameter like `param1=value1&param2=value2` and then split.

Comment: I have no issues accessing the parameters,but in my scenario there are two many parameters to be taken as input, Also I am able to feed the input . The problem is it comes to a very lengthy form.

Comment: lets say A(dropdown) \nB(dropdown) \nC(dropdown. I want the three parameters to appear as   A(dropdown) B(dropdown) C(dropdown) in a horizontal line so that its looks a little less clumsy-  @GaurangShah